# Adding two Selects with similar results and mutually exclusive values

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this table:

field1 = 'name'; field2 = 'value1'; field3 = 'value2';

Value2 and value3 are 0 or 1 and are mutually exclusive (that is, if field2 is 1 for name XXX then field3 is 0).
Now I want to do a Select which results in this:

```
position1   position2
name1       name2
```

I've tried:

```
select field1 as position1 from table where field2 = 1
union all
select field1 as position2 from table where field3 = 1
```

But obviously that didn't work. Then I tried:

```
select field1 as position1, '0' as position2 from table where field2 = 1
union all
select field1 as position2, '0' as position1 from table where field3 = 1
```

And didn't work either.

For some design reasons I need to this in a Select, although I believe (haven't checked if I have permissions though) I can create temporal tables on pl/Sql.

IIRC this was possible but I cannot remember how.

Comment: please post sample Input and output

Comment: your table has only 2 rows?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming table "t1" looks like this -

```
SID NUMBER(0) /* Service ID */
NAME VARCHAR2(10) /* Employee name */
BOSS NUMBER(0) /* Boss boolean */ 
SECRETARY NUMBER(0) /* Secretary boolean */
```

Using the following query should result in a better explain plan -

```
select sid, max(boss) pos1, max(secretary) pos2
from (select sid,
             decode(boss,1,name) boss,
             decode(secretary,1,name) secretary
      from t1)
group by sid;
```

If you add an index on the "sid" column, even better.

Here's some trial code - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/742cc0/11

Answer (score 1):

It isn't 100% clear what you want from your question, but if I had to guess - you could at least use subqueries to get what you want:

```
select 
   (select field1 from table where field2 = 1) as position1, 
   (select field1 from table where field3 = 1) as position2 
from dual;
```

This will not work though if you have multiple items in your table that match `where field2 = 1`. In which case, you could either use `rownum = 1` or some other limiter or aggregate like `Max()`, etc...

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    T1.field1 AS position1,
    T2.field1 AS position2
FROM
    MyTable T1
LEFT OUTER JOIN MyTable T2 ON
    T2.id = T1.id AND
    T2.field3 = 1
WHERE
    T1.field2 = 1
```

I hope those aren't really your column names of course. Also, the two bit columns that basically contain the same data should probably be combined. For example, EmployeeType (1=manager, 2=secretary). Without knowing your system that might not be the case, but it's likely.

Answer (score 0):

First thanks for the input.

Basically I have a list of services who have a manager and a secretary; if you're a manager you can't be a secretary and the other way around.
I forgot to add the service ID that would've made everything easier but already found the answer:

```
select t1.position1, t2.position2 from
(select field1 as position1 from table where field2 = 1) t1
left join
(select field1 as position2 from table where field3 = 1) t2
on t1.id = t2.id
```

This works like a charm :D

Comment: I don't think that you need the subqueries there. You should just be able to join the tables directly.